# MDX error trying to compare one hierarchy level to another one

Tags: multidimensional-array, ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I have an MDX issue that I really don't understand with a 5 level hierarchy "SEGMENTATION" : AFFAIRE/NIVEAU 1/ NIVEAU 2/NIVEAU 3/NIVEAU 4

I want to compare "NIVEAU 1" sub-levels weight to "Niveau 1".
For instance, I want to know for each 'NIVEAU 3' members its contributions part for its "NIVEAU 1".

I've tried a bunch of things, but nothing works properly. I don't get the trick and is stucked to :

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[TEST] AS'
iif(ISEMPTY(([Segmentation].[Niveau1], [Measures].[Total])) OR ([Segmentation].[Niveau1],[Measures].[Total]) = 0
    , NULL
    ,[Measures].[Total] / ([Segmentation].[Niveau1], [Measures].[Total])
)'
          
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[TEST],[Measures].[Total]} ON COLUMNS
, NON EMPTY { [Segmentation].[Niveau2]}
ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Segmentation].[Niveau1].&[8589934592]&[1|DESC111] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [CUBE]) // Only one "Niveau 1" focus
```

---

And I get :

[image]

```
<Niveau 2>                TEST           Total
SF - C...                 #Error      25143658
SF - M...                 #Error       1638913,5
ZZZ  ...                  #Error      90468628
```

#Error : **The EqualTo function expects a string or numeric expression for argument 1. A tuple set expression was used.**

The expected result is :

```
<Niveau 2>                 TEST         Total
SF - C...                21,44%      25143658
SF - M...                 1,40%       1638913,5
ZZZ  ...                 77,16%      90468628
```

21,4% = 25143658/(25143658+1638913,5+90468628)

What's wrong with my MDX?
Is there a mistake among the dimension or hierarchy set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are written as comma separated lists of members. What you have is a dimension.

Try

```
[Segmentation].CurrentMember.Parent
```

Instead of

```
[Segmentation].[Niveau1]
```

On your measure definition.

[EDIT] As mentioned in a comment, the goal is a solution that works on all levels. The solution is to use

```
Ancestor( [Segmentation].CurrentMember, [Segmentation].[Niveau1] )
```

in the Tuple used in the custom measure definition.

Comment: Thanks for answering. [Segmentation].CurrentMember.Parent works fine with "NIVEAU 2" but won't work with "Niveau 3 & 4". We always need to sum the "Niveau 1" level...

Comment: Answer edited to include those cases too.

Comment: The use of ancestor works as expected : thank you nsousa ^^

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nsousa, I'm now using :

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Total Niveau1] AS'
iif([Segmentation].CURRENTMEMBER.level.ordinal>=2
    ,(Ancestor([Segmentation].CurrentMember,[Segmentation].[Niveau1] ),[Measures].[Total])
    ,([Segmentation].CURRENTMEMBER, [Measures].[Total])
    )
'
MEMBER [Measures].[TEST] AS'
DIVIDE([Measures].[Societe],[Measures].[Total Niveau1])
',FORMAT_STRING = 'Percent'

 SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[TEST],[Measures].[Societe],[Measures].[Total]} ON COLUMNS
 , NON EMPTY { [Segmentation].[Niveau3]}
  ON ROWS FROM [CUBE]
```

[image]